# How to make this equations aligned

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, cases

I have an equation as below, I want `text1` and `text2`, `text3` are aligned as well.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    A &= B \quad \text{text1}\\
    C &=
    \begin{cases}
      1 &        \text{text2} \\
      0 &        \text{text3}
    \end{cases} &
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to insert the same spacing as for the `cases` (only the first column), and correct for a "null delimiter" on the right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A &= \makebox[0pt][l]{$B$} 
    \hphantom{\begin{cases} 1\\0\end{cases}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \text{text1} \\
  C &=
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{text2} \\
      0 & \text{text3}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The element `B` is inserted with a zero-width `r`ight overlap (equivalent to `\rlap`) to not interfere with the placement of `text1`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

An alternative where array environment with @{quad} alignment and {... \right is used.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    A &= B \quad\quad  \text{text1}\\
    C &=
\left \{
    \begin{array}{r@{\quad}l}
      1 &        \text{text2} \\
      0 &        \text{text3}
    \end{array} \right . &
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```